# Syntax confusion between counting elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax, counting

`$(this).siblings()` returns:

```
[<section style class=​"white">​…​</section>​
, <section style class=​"white">​…​</section>​
, <section style=​"display:​ none">​…​</section>​
, <section style=​"display:​ none">​…​</section>​
, <section style=​"display:​ none">​…​</section>​
, <section style=​"display:​ none">​…​</section>​
, <section style=​"display:​ none">​…​</section>​]
```

so there are 7 sections, two of which (currrently) have the class `white`.  Once the `parent()` section is hidden, I can no longer use the code:

```
var hidden = ($(this).siblings().filter(':visible').length);
```

to see how many are visible, I need to count the classes that are white.  after a long while, I was able to get this to work:

```
var hidden=0;
$(this).siblings().each(function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass('white')) {hidden++;};
});
```

Why am I having to loop through each sibling and cannot use one the following, or another one line to count the ones with class `'white'`:

```
var hidden = ($(this).siblings().filter(':white').length); or
var hidden = ($(this).siblings().filter('white').length);
```

or

```
var hidden = ($(this).siblings().hasClass('white').length);
```

or

```
var hidden = ($(this).siblings().is(':white').length); or
var hidden = ($(this).siblings().is('white').length);
```

Comment: Post your HTML please. Or a jsFiddle.

Comment: TIP :using `$('.fs.btn.heading.abstract')` is not a good idea

Comment: sorry, that was to identify the specific element I was testing, I have edited.   Why is it not a good idea though? I am new to JQuery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why go through the trouble of `.filter()`, `.hasClass()`, `.is()`, and looping? [Can't you use `.sibling()`'s argument to filter the siblings instead](http://jsfiddle.net/RZzZV/) and get those that are "white"?

```
$(this).siblings('.white').length
```

Comment: Ah yes! the `.` to signify class.   however, I did not know you could pass an argument to the sibling().  Could I also pass ':visible' in this line: `var hidden = ($(this).siblings().filter(':visible').length);` and make it: `var hidden = ($(this).siblings(':visible').length);`?

Comment: Yes. [The docs says `[selector]`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) which means *any valid selector*